# ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row- multiple values needed

Tags: sql, oracle11g, operators, row, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have the following SQL query on Oracle

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN (SELECT DISTINCT(trim(z.m_base_acct))
      FROM acc_mapping_rep z
      WHERE z.m_dyn_acct=b.m_en_credit
      AND z.M_REF_DATA  =b.M_REF_DATA) IN 'SAMANOS'
    THEN '7200000888001X'

  END AS M_EN_CRDR

FROM 
acc_journal_rep b
AND b.m_ref_data       = 41091
AND b.m_en_date        = '21-SEP-15'
AND b.m_entity         = 'LN'
AND b.m_nb_trn         = 0
```

I am having the oracle error ORA-01427. Due to the line where I have a case when condition knowing that I did put IN operator instead of equal.
Please advise. I need to have multiple values in the case condition.

Comment: This would be much easier to digest if you provided a minimalized example or your problem. I believe that I see the issue (IN with a single value), but I really have no idea what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: ok i will one minute

Comment: i want to test the values in the select statement that exists in the case condition (returning 3 rows) and check if on of those values are equal to the value SAMANOS then I want the value  to be 7200000888001X @TomH

Comment: I'm not saying you won't get an answer but that query is quite a lot to digest. Can you try and give us a simple example of the problem. You can use something like www.sqlfiddle.com to demonstrate.

Comment: is that better ? @TomH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If as you've shown you only have one value to compare, `'SAMANOS'`, then you can just swap the terms:

```
SELECT 
  CASE
    WHEN 'SAMANOS' IN (SELECT DISTINCT(trim(z.m_base_acct))
      FROM acc_mapping_rep z
      WHERE z.m_dyn_acct=b.m_en_credit
      AND z.M_REF_DATA  =b.M_REF_DATA)
    THEN '7200000888001X'
  END AS M_EN_CRDR
...
```

You could also left-join to the `acc_mapping_rep` table, but the `distinct` and `trim` are slightly worrying - if those are actually needed then it becomes a little more complicated and you'd need to left-join to an inline view of that table.

The `b.m_en_date = '21-SEP-15'` is also worrying; if `m_en_date` is a DATE column then you're relying on implicit conversions and your session NLS settings. It would be better to use `to_date()`, or with a fixed value a date literal: `b.m_en_date = date '2015-09-21'`.

Your original longer code would also benefit from using ANSI joins instead of the old Oracle-specific `(+)` outer join operator.